# How to get the CPU usage of iPhone/iPad?

Tags: iphone, cpu-usage

I saw in A+ monitor, it can show CPU Idle, CPU usage, CPU System. Which API should be used to get the these information? I have searched and I use the getloadavg function, but it can only return the CPU usage. Also it is not correctly for it will always be more than 90%.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Most of these can be retrieved using the appropriate `sysctl()` selectors.

Comment: sysctl can get the CPU static information like cpu numbers, I haven't seen where can I get the runtime information. Could you please give me more details? Thank you very much!